# How to activate bootstrap.tagsinput for inputs added after DOM loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tags, bootstrap-tags-input

I'm dynamically adding some fields that I'd like to be tag fields.

I'm using [bootstrap.tagsinput](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)

Any `input`s marked with `data-role=tagsinput` in the original document turn out just fine. However, if I add any more using jQuery for instance,

**How do I apply bootstrap.tagsinput to them?**

Comment: You'll need to use a callback on the function that creates the new tags to run the Boostrap function. We could help more if you'd show some code.

Comment: So you're saying I should reload the whole <script> every time I add a new set of fields via a user ineteraction? I'd show code but there really isn't more to it than what I said. User clicks button -> fields appear, except they dont get "taggified

Comment: I'm not saying that because I don't know what your code looks like. Show it if you want more help.

Comment: I guess you can either select the element using jQuery and apply the `.tagsinput()` method to it, or perhaps apply it to all elements with the `data-role` using `$('[data-role="tagsinput"]').tagsinput()`. Not sure if you can apply the plugin to the same element twice though.

Answer (score 1):

I just did:

```
$('#input-tags').tagsinput('destroy');
$('#input-tags').tagsinput();
```

This worked without having to add and remove all tags.